# Need help simplifying boolean algebra equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have the following equation:
$$
P = y\bar{z} + \bar{x}(x + \bar{y}(y + \bar{z}(z + x))) + (x + z)(\bar{x} + y) + \overline{xy+\bar{x}\bar{z}+y\bar{z}}
$$
When simplified it comes down to $x + y + z$.

I tried, but I can't seem to get to that solution.
Can someone try to simplify it step by step? Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your steps made. First you have use De Morgan on the last term and the used distributivity to simplify the terms.

Comment: Without showing us the steps you've taken, we cannot show you where is mistake is.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
P = y\bar{z} + \bar{x}(x + \bar{y}(y + \bar{z}(z + x))) + (x + z)(\bar{x} + y) + \overline{xy+\bar{x}\bar{z}+y\bar{z}}
\end{equation}

To simplify $(1)$, it helps to break it up first. The second term can be expanded and evaluated in the way of $(2)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\bar{x}(x + \bar{y}(y + \bar{z}(z + x)))\\
0 + \bar{x}\bar{y}(y + \bar{z}(z + x)))\\
0+ \bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}(z + x)\\
0
\end{equation}

The third term in the way of $(3)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
(x+z)(\bar{x}+y)\\
0+xy+z\bar{x}+zy
\end{equation}

The forth term reduces to $(4)$, using [De-Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\overline{xy+\bar{x}\bar{z}+y\bar{z}}\\
(\bar{x}+\bar{y})(x+z)(\bar{y}+z)\\
(0+\bar{x}z+\bar{y}x+\bar{y}z)(\bar{y}+z)\\
\bar{x}z\bar{y}+\bar{x}z+\bar{y}x+\bar{y}xz+\bar{y}z+\bar{y}z\\
\bar{x}z+\bar{y}x+\bar{y}z\\
\end{equation}

Bringing it all together $(1~-~4)$, we simplify $P$.

\begin{align}
P &= (y\bar{z})+0+(xy+z\bar{x}+zy)+(\bar{x}z+\bar{y}x+\bar{y}z)\\
&=(zy+z\bar{y})+(y\bar{z}+yz)+(xy+x\bar{y})\\
&=z+y+x
\end{align}